# How do I detect pygame collisions?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm currently developing a small game with pygame and I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to check for collisions. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame), but I can't use the `pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, wall_group, True)` because my called player isn't a 'sprite', it's a class that I've created (that uses the functionality of normal shapes (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html)).

If anyone could figure a way that I can detect collisions and explain to me shortly about the difference between 'sprite' and just a normal shape like circle/rectangle I would appreciate it.

Comment: Sprites have collision detection built-in.  It's one of the purposes of a sprite.  If you don't use sprites, you'll have to invent your own collision detection (or find a library to help you).   See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987567/8441876) for further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use pygame's collition detection funcions (like `pygame.sprite.spritecollide`), your class does not need to be a subclass of pygame's `Sprite`.

Thanks to python's duck typing, the actual class does not matter, as long as your class behaves like a `Sprite`. In this context, it just means that your class should have a `rect` attribute, and it should be a `Rect` (again, technically, it does not need to be a `Rect`, only "look like" one).

Given a simple class like this:

```
>>> class Foo():
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.rect=pygame.rect.Rect(100, 100, 100, 100)
```

we can use `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` like this:

```
>>> f=Foo()
>>> g=Foo()

>>> pygame.sprite.spritecollide(f, [g], False)
[<__main__.Foo instance at 0x0000000003C6DF48>]
```

Also see how the second argument isn't a `Group`, but a simple `List`, but python does not care, since the only thing that matters in this case is that you can iterate over the object. If you would pass `True` as the third argument, this would fail, since `spritecollide` would try to call `sprites()` and the second argument and `kill()` on the elements inside.

Likewise, if you want to e.g. use pixel perfect collision detection, you need a `mask` attribute etc. So you should use the `Sprite` class anyway since it offers some more stuff like managing groups. Also, everytime you want to store a position or a size, consider using pygame's `Rect` class, since it's quite powerfull and it's used/expected in a lot of pygame functions.

**tl;dr:** Use pygame's `Sprite` class. There's probably no good reason for you to not do it, and a bunch of good reason to actually use it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help man, and I'll use your advice and change my classes into Sprite classes. Thanks alot !(: